# navigating through desired views (while skipping some views) using UINavigationBar back button

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a UICollectionView to show a list of images.
1)By clicking on any cell the image and some description about it is displayed in the resulting view controller(using a push segue).

2)When i swipe from the left/right edge(using PanGesture) i need to display the details of the previous/next image in the collection view.

3)But the back button of the navigation bar has to take me back to the collection view and not to the previous displayed details (shown by the PanGesture).

I know how to get 1 and 2 done but don't have a concrete idea to get the 3rd job done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: cant add images yet(low rep). 1) http://imgur.com/WRfjv1I  2) http://imgur.com/NNUk18j  3) http://imgur.com/hrB74rD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after researching a lot i found that using a collection view with each cell taking up the whole screen is the best way to go about solving this issue.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can find your desired UIViewController in your navigation stack using `for` loop. Try this. This is in Swift

```
 for (var i = 0; i < self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count; i++) {

                if (self.navigationController?.viewControllers[i].isKindOfClass(YourViewController) == true) {

                    println("is sw \(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i])")

                    (self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i] as! YourViewController)

                    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i] as! YourViewController, animated: true)


                    break;
                }
```

Comment: but then i have to add this code and custom back button to all the viewControllers starting from the current views.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from one view to another (e.g. by showing a detail view of your images one after the other, then all these views are internally piled up as a stack.

Thus, if you want to jump directly to a view somewhere in between this stack (e.g. the collection view), then you can use the Unwind Segue.

In your case it should work like this:

First, in your collection view (i.e. your back button destination) you need to implement a UIStoryboard Segue as follows

```
@IBAction func myGoBackPoint(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    println("Jump directly back here from any other view")
}
```

Then, in the storyboard of your detail view you ctrl-drag directly to top rightmost Exit marker and choose the previously created back button destination:

[image: Unwind Segue]

In the code of the detail view implement the "go back instruction"

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "My Unwind Segue" {
      if let myUnwindSegue = segue.destinationViewController as? MyCollectionViewController {
         // prepare for segue
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of using unwind segue , but cant connect it to the back button provided (implicitly) by iOS . Have to create a custom button (with back icon image) for the particular detail view controller and connect that to the exit segue. I'll look for another way , if there isn't then ill follow this. Thank you